# SoftLayer_Account::getOpenStackObjectStorage returns nothing

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have 6 Open Stack Object Storage Account, but using following URL returns nothing on content field with an RC of 200.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getOpenStackObjectStorage.json
```

Is this the wrong URL?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the method is deprecated, you need to use SoftLayer_Account::getHubNetworkStorage method

for more information about softlayer object Storage see http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs#utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_content=manage-object-storage-using-rest-api&utm_campaign=developer_rest-api

Regarding to your question about the users who have access, you need look for the users who have the following permissions:

"Manage CDN", "Manage CDN File Transfer" and "Manage Storage"

all the users who have those permissions have access to all your object storages in your account, it is not possible to set access for a specific object storage.

the methods which can help you are:

get the permissions of an user
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getPermissions

List all the users in your account:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers

Regards

Regards

Comment: The suggested REST API works.Thank you.  How do I retrieve the users that have access to each Object Storage?

Comment: I updated my answer. please do not forget mark it as the correct and vote.